# MySQL (MariaDB) too many connections that don't close?

Tags: debian, mysql, mariadb

I have recently acquired my first VPS to run a mysql server for my minecraft server, I have setup MariaDB, it's using the default settings at present.
I tested it last night with one plugin (GriefPrevention v7.8) to see if it was even possible to use remotely, it worked, but checking out `htop` there are tens of mysql processes now! I only briefly tested the plugin with this VPS mysql server, are these open connections that were not closed?

I tried restarting mysql but that didn't stop them. I also Have a web interface that runs on the VPS box that pulls information into a web UI, but I haven't advertised the URL of the VPS so it shouldn't be loading.

1. How can I see what's causing these?
2. I presume at this rate, they will all just build up and crash the server?
3. How can I limit these, should I?
4. Should I create a new user for each plugin to access the database remotely when I push them live to use it?
5. Why are these "connections" still open, when the plugin isn't in use and I have restarted mysql?

[image: HTOP preview of VPS tree of mysql]

Answer (score 1):

It should be okay. Unlike the `top` command, `htop` by default lists all the threads along with the processes. So all the 'mysqld' that you are seeing are not processes, but threads.

Do this:

Grab the PID of a few mysql entries you see in the `htop` output and grep it in the output of `ps`.

Eg:

`ps -ef | grep 14082`

Here, the grep probably won't return any mysql processes to you. Now try this:

`ps -eLf | grep 14082`

And now you will see grep returning you a mysql process which is not really a process, but a thread.

The `L` option will ask `ps` to list all the Light Weight Processes(threads) as well. So grep found the TID you have since that is a Light Weight Process or thread. Check the `top` output and you will probably see only one or two MySQL processes.

Additionally, get the PID of your MySQL process from `ps -ef` output and use `pstree` to see all the threads created from that process.

`pstree -p <PIDofMySQL>`

Comment: Ahh thanks @sree I feel silly for not checking out top now! There are literally 2 MySQL process in here, although the ps -ef | grep 14082 is displaying a mysql process (I think).
Sorry for screenshots, all image hosting sites are blocked at work! http://vps.piratemc.com/screens/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2014.02.54.png

&

http://vps.piratemc.com/screens/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2014.03.35.png

IM starting to learn more about how Unix manages processes now, sorry for being so naive. Do you think this is usual practise of mysql? I will have to give it some load to see what it can take :)

Comment: @GodsDead Yes, looking at the images you have posted, 14082:83 are threads and 14064 is the process from which those threads came from. You can use `ps -ef | grep mysql` to see the actual process. You can also upvote my answer if you found it useful :).